# Desktop FPS drops

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I have pretty powerful set up, but I get frame drops in my gnome desktop.

It usually happens when I exit the "Activities" and in the Activities. It doesnt freeze my computer, it just kinda makes the animations not smooth and "stuttery", while its not a huge problem it very much annoys me.

System info:

```
System:    Host: tomas-MS-7918 Kernel: 4.4.0-36-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: Gnome 3.18.5
           Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   Mobo: MSI model: Z97 GAMING 3 (MS-7918) v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: V2.0 date: 04/22/2014
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4790K (-HT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 4400 MHz 1: 4400 MHz 2: 4303 MHz 3: 4398 MHz 4: 4400 MHz 5: 4375 MHz
           6: 4270 MHz 7: 4362 MHz 8: 4401 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GM204 [GeForce GTX 980]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: GeForce GTX 980/PCIe/SSE2 GLX Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 361.42
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GM204 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel 9 Series Family HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Samson C03U multi-pattern microphone driver: USB Audio
           Card-4 Logitech HD Webcam C525 driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.4.0-36-generic
Network:   Card: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: alx
           IF: enp3s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full mac: 44:8a:5b:a0:9e:aa
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my setup, except I use Unity with Nvidia proprietary drivers. It randomly gets laggy, and I have to restart.

Comment: i dont have to retard because i only happens when i press the super key